# C# Chart Shown not correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, charts

I have run into this problem. I have a chart the integer values of which is updated real-time. When I sketch the curves I see some knots in the curves, the chartType is spline and you are welcome to see the code in the sequel. Any remedies?
Unfortunately I cannot post the figure but at the data points instead of having a smooth figure I see curves turn around the data point once and then .... Its like instead of a "L" like curve I see a "b" like curve.

Thanks

```
               //dt2=new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
               //dt3 and dt4 are some integer and float values respectively.

                chrt1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dt2,dt3);
                chrt1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(dt2,dt4);
                chrt1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                chrt1.Series[1].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "ss";
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.LabelStyle.Format = "ddd d MMM (HH:mm tt)";
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Interval = 1;
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.IntervalOffset = 1;
                minDate = dt2.AddMinutes(-1.1); 
                maxDate = dt2; // or DateTime.Now;
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
                chrt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
```

Comment: Did you try FastLine chart type instead of Spline ?

Answer (score 0):

Change series ChartType  to Line or FastLine.

To do access ChartType property for each series and change them to either FastLine or Line type

```
  chrt1.Series[0].ChartType=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine;
  chrt1.Series[1].ChartType=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine;
```

Comment: Thanks, 
With FastLine or Line it works fine with the cost of appearance.
I kind of need the spline chartType.
M